# De-bugging Google Analytics Link & Download Tracking

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm trying to install some script on one of my websites to track outbound links and downloads in Google Analytics but I'm not having much luck. This is the [script](http://www.blastam.com/blog/index.php/2013/09/howto-track-downloads-links-universalanalytics) that I'm using (if anyone knows of a better guide or script I'd love to hear about it).

**My question is this:** How can I check whether it's working without using Google Analytics? Is there a way I can see the events or data that's being sent when a link or download is clicked using Firebug or Developer Tools?

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use the GA autotrack plugins instead (https://github.com/googleanalytics/autotrack) - while not an "offical" part of the product those are written by a Google engineer (who also maintains some presence at stackoverflow).

However it is easy to see if this works - Google offers the [Google Tag Assistant](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk?hl=en) (for Chrome) to test GA integrations, there is a [Chrome GA Debugger Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en), or you might simply open the developer tools in your browser and inspect the "network" tab. If you filter for calls to google-analytics.com/collect you should see outgoing calls and can look at the query parameters to see if your data is sent properly; if the calls return a http status of 200 the data should turn up in your GA account.

Comment: That's a super helpful answer Eike, thank you so much! Do you know if the autotrack plugin also tracks file downloads?

Comment: You'd probably use the eventTracker plugin (part of autotrack) for that, however you'd need to add data attributes (data-event-category="download" data-event-action="filename").  The plugin would pick those up and automatically send an event.

Comment: Thanks Eike, do you happen to know of any scripts that could automatically track downloads without having to add markup to all download links, that also plays nicely with the autotrack plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Eike's response I've now chosen to solve this challenge by installing [Google Tag Manager](http://tagmanager.google.com/) and then creating custom tags to track things like outbound links, email links and download links. Here's a [guide](http://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/track-file-downloads-in-gtm-v2/#gref) that helped me to setup download tracking, hope others find it useful.